# Newline in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-styles, labels, automata

How do I get the edge from q5 to qA to break into two lines? I looked at other posts and nothing seemed to work.

Edit: Added macros and formatting

```
%==============================================================================
% Homework X, CS 254 (Fall 2020)
%
% Fill out this information for every assignment. This template has been adapted from one by Layla Oesper.
%==============================================================================
\newcommand{\thishw}{\bf Homework 6}
\newcommand{\myname}{}  % Your name here.
\newcommand{\timespent}{}
\newcommand{\mypair}{}  % Your homework pair, including you.
\newcommand{\mygroup}{}  % Your homework group, including you.
\newcommand{\mycredit}{None} 
%==============================================================================
% Formatting parameters.
%==============================================================================

\documentclass[11pt]{article} % 11pt article, want AMS fonts.
\makeatletter                   % Make '@' accessible.
\pagestyle{myheadings}              % We do our own page headers.
\def\@oddhead{\bf CS 254 - \thishw{} \hfill \myname } % Here they are.
%\def\thesection{Component\hskip-1em\ }     % Section headlines.
\oddsidemargin=0in              % Left margin minus 1 inch.
\evensidemargin=0in             % Same for even-numbered pages.
\textwidth=6.5in                % Text width (8.5in - margins).
\topmargin=0in                  % Top margin minus 1 inch.
\headsep=0.2in                  % Distance from header to body.
\textheight=8in                 % Body height (incl. footnotes)
\skip\footins=4ex               % Space above first footnote.
\hbadness=10000                 % No "underfull hbox" messages.
\makeatother                    % Make '@' special again.
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

%==============================================================================
% Import Packages.  You can add anything you need here.
%==============================================================================

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

%==============================================================================
% Macros.
%==============================================================================
\newcommand{\component}[1]{\section*{Component #1}}     % Component.
\newcommand{\challenge}[1]{\section*{Supplementary Challenge #1}}       % Supplementary challenge.
\newcommand{\totaltime}[1]{\subsection*{Time spent} \timespent} % Time spent
\newcommand{\hwpair}{\subsection*{Homework Pair} \mypair } % Homework pair.
\newcommand{\hwgroup}{\subsection*{Homework Group} \mygroup} % Homework group.
\newcommand{\credit}{\subsection*{Other Credit} \mycredit} % Other people to credit.         

%==============================================================================
% Title, time spent and collaborations.
% Note: You shouldn't edit this section.
%==============================================================================

\begin{document}
\centerline{\LARGE\thishw{}}

\vskip1em
\noindent \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\totaltime 

\hwpair

\hwgroup

\credit

\end{minipage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  COMPONENT 1  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\component{1}

Note: I will be using \_ to indicate blank space. I am also making the assumption that $i > 0, j > 0, k > 0$.

    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm, thin,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily}]
    
      \node[main node] (0) {$q_0$};
      \node[main node] (1) [right of=0] {$q_1$};
      \node[main node] (2) [right of=1] {$q_1$};
      \node[main node] (3) [above right of=2] {$q_2$};
      \node[main node] (4) [right of=3] {$q_3$};
      \node[main node] (5) [below right of=2] {$q_4$};
      \node[main node] (6) [right of=5] {$q_5$};

      \node[main node] (7) [above right of=6] {$q_A$};

      \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
        (0) edge node [above] {$\epsilon, \epsilon$;z} (1)
        (1) edge node [above] {C,$\epsilon$;c} (2)
        (2) edge [loop right] node {C,$\epsilon$;c} (2)
            edge node [left] {A,c;$\epsilon$} (3)
            edge node [left] {A,$\epsilon$;a} (5)
        (3) edge [loop above] node {A,c;$\epsilon$} (3)
            edge node [above] {A,z;$\epsilon$} (4)
            edge node [below] {T,c;$\epsilon$} (7)
        (4) edge [loop above] node {A,$\epsilon$;$\epsilon$} (4)
            edge node [right] {T,$\epsilon$;$\epsilon$} (7)
        (5) edge [loop below] node {A,$\epsilon$;a} (5)
            edge node [below] {T,a;$\epsilon$} (6)
        (6) edge [loop below] node {T,a;$\epsilon$} (6)
            edge node [below] {T,c;$\epsilon$\\ \_,a;$\epsilon$} (7);
    \end{tikzpicture}

We cannot create a deterministic version of this PDA because it is not possible to check that $i \ne j$ and $j \ne k$ at the same time.

\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  COMPONENT 2  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\component{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \item
    \item
\end{enumerate}

\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  COMPONENT 3  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\component{3}


\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  COMPONENT 4  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\component{4}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item [\textbf{10.5:}]
    \item [\textbf{10.7}]
\end{enumerate}


\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  COMPONENT 5  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\component{5}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item [\textbf{10.6:}]
\end{enumerate}

\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  COMPONENT 6  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\component{6}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item [\textbf{10.15:}]
\end{enumerate}


\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  COMPONENT 7  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\component{7}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item [\textbf{11.6:}]
\end{enumerate}

\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  COMPONENT 8  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\component{8}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item [\textbf{11.9:}]
\end{enumerate}

\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SUPPLEMENTARY CHALLENGE 1  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\challenge{1}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item [11.7]
\end{enumerate}

\newpage


\end{document}
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  See if `... node [below, align=center]  {T,c;$\epsilon$\\ \_,a;$\epsilon$} ... ` gives what you like to have. For more complete answer please provide copy of code from your editor, not its image. The best as small but complete document, which can be compiled as it is.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks! I tried your suggestion but it didn't have the intended effect. I made a quick edit and added all of the macros and styling. Does this help?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Please copy your code from your editor and paste it in question. We can't compile its image. Retyping your code is not fun ...

Comment: @Zarko My bad! Here we go

Comment: Please, explain what you mean with "intended effect"? Suggestion in my comment write edge label in two lines!

Comment: @Zarko I'm sorry, I didn't read your comment correctly. It all works now. Thanks!

Comment: See my answer. Does it gives what you like to have? In it I took a liberty and made some off-topic changes with goal to make code shorter.

Comment: Note that using [align] is equivalent to putting a tabular into the node.  Usnge [text width] is equivalent to putting a \parbox into the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your document example I made the following MWE (Minimal Working Example):

```
\documentclass [margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
           node distance = 20mm, on grid,
       every edge/.style = {draw, -Stealth, shorten >=1pt}, 
every edge quotes/.style = {auto,
                            font=\sffamily\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                            inner sep=2pt, align=center},
     state/.append style = {minimum  size=1.5em, inner sep=2pt}
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={state}]
\node (0) {$q_0$};
\node (1) [right=of  0] {$q_1$};
\node (2) [right=of  1] {$q_1$};
\node (3) [above right=of  2] {$q_2$};
\node (4) [right=of  3] {$q_3$};
\node (5) [below right=of  2] {$q_4$};
\node (6) [right=of  5] {$q_5$};
\node (7) [above right=of  6] {$q_A$};
    \end{scope}
\path   (0) edge ["{{$\epsilon, \epsilon$;z}}"] (1)
        (1) edge ["{C,$\epsilon$;c}"] (2)
        (2) edge [loop right,"{C,$\epsilon$;c}"] (2)
            edge ["{A,c;$\epsilon$}"] (3)
            edge ["{A,$\epsilon$;a}" '] (5)
        (3) edge [loop above,"{A,c;$\epsilon$}"] (3)
            edge ["{A,z;$\epsilon$}"] (4)
            edge ["{T,c;$\epsilon$}" '] (7)
        (4) edge [loop above,"{A,$\epsilon;\epsilon$}"] (4)
            edge ["{T,$\epsilon;\epsilon$}"] (7)
        (5) edge [loop below,"{A,$\epsilon$;a}"] (5)
            edge ["{T,a;$\epsilon$}" '] (6)
        (6) edge [loop below,"{T,a;$\epsilon$}"] (6)
            edge ["{T,c;$\epsilon$\\ \_,a;$\epsilon$}" '] (7);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which in compilation produce:

[image]

In MWE are in comparison to your document example are done the following changes:

- due to focus just on image is used `standalone` document class which enable to show just an image. However, it has not any influence on use of picture code in any document
- added are two libraries: `automata` and `positioning`, `arrows` is replaced by `arrows.meta`
- for positioning of vertices are used syntax from the library positioning (observe that now `=` and `of` are interchanged), which define distance between node borders,
- vertices (nodes) are positioned on grid
- in code are grouped in `scope`, which enable to write shorter code
- instead of `edge notes` are used edge quotes. For them is defined new style (`every edge quotes`, which automatically positing labels on left side of edge, however, in diagram are four exception, where for positioning is used `swap` options (actually its shortness `'`)
- redefined are used style (`state` instead of `main node`, style for edge nodes.

Hopefully, the showed result is what you after.